# Using guide_legend with geom_bar in ggplot

Tags: r, geom-bar

Is there anyway of making geom_legend work with geom_bar? I want to have too lines in my legend. It works for geom_line but not for geom_bar charts.

It works fine when I used it here:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour = z))+
      guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

The code it doesn't work for is as follows:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
       geom_bar()+
       guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 2))
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `col` to `fill` in the last line. Color is not the mapped aesthetic, fill is.